# Отключить скрол для вкладок TabLayout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-tablayout

На экране использую 2 вкладки. В качестве вкладок у меня установлен кастомный layout (так как нужны разные цвета текста и имитация кнопки). Но почему-то добавился скрол к Tablayout всего для двух вкладок. Поэтому не виден правый край 2 вкладки. Пробовал применить атрибут `tabMode="fixed"` - не помогло

Разметка

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/coordinatorFirst"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/light_background_app_bar">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainAppbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/main_bg"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainCollapsing"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="@color/transparent"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabsIndicator"
            style="@style/TabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:padding="2dp"
            app:tabIndicator="@drawable/selector_background_tabs"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="42dp"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabRippleColor="@null"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<ru.diitcenter.peretz2.presentation.utils.NonSwipeableViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mainAppbar"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

В коде

```
private fun initCustomTabs() {
    //Установка цветов при первоначальном запуске
    tabsIndicator.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(
            tabsIndicator.context,
            R.drawable.round_dark_tab_layout
    )
    mainAppbar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(
            mainAppbar.context,
            R.color.dark_background_app_bar))

    tabsIndicator.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(ContextCompat.getColor(
            tabsIndicator.context,
            R.color.dark_background_app_bar
    ))

    //Отображение текста и иконки на первой вкладке
    val tabLinearLayout = LayoutInflater.from(context)
            .inflate(R.layout.custom_tabs_for_tab_layout, null) as LinearLayout
    val tabTitleLeft = tabLinearLayout.findViewById<View>(R.id.textViewTab) as TextView
    tabTitleLeft.text = getString(R.string.title_peretz)
    tabTitleLeft.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.logo, 0)
    tabTitleLeft.compoundDrawablePadding = 6
    tabTitleLeft.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(
            tabTitleLeft.context,
            R.color.white
    ))

    //Отображение текста и иконки на второй вкладке
    val tabLinearLayout1 = LayoutInflater.from(context)
            .inflate(R.layout.custom_tabs_for_tab_layout, null) as LinearLayout
    val tabTitleRight = tabLinearLayout1.findViewById<View>(R.id.textViewTab) as TextView
    tabTitleRight.text = getString(R.string.title_green_apple)
    tabTitleRight.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.ic_green_apple, 0)
    tabTitleRight.compoundDrawablePadding = 1
    tabTitleRight.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(
            tabTitleLeft.context,
            R.color.titleRightGray
    ))

    tabsIndicator.getTabAt(0)?.customView = tabTitleLeft
    tabsIndicator.getTabAt(1)?.customView = tabTitleRight

    tabsIndicator.addOnTabSelectedListener(object : TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
        override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {}
        override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {}

        override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
            when (tab?.position) {
                0 -> onLeftTabClicked(tabTitleLeft, tabTitleRight)
                1 -> onRightTabClicked(tabTitleLeft, tabTitleRight)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась с помощью добавления метода, который устанавливает `margin`

```
 private fun setMargins(){
    //Левый tab
    val tabLeft = (tabsToolbar.getChildAt(0) as ViewGroup).getChildAt(0)
    val valuesLeft = tabLeft.layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams

    valuesLeft.rightMargin = this.resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.margin_selector)
    valuesLeft.leftMargin = this.resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.margin_selector)

    //Правый tab
    val tabRight = (tabsToolbar.getChildAt(0) as ViewGroup).getChildAt(1)
    val valuesRight = tabRight.layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams

    valuesRight.rightMargin = this.resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.margin_selector)
    valuesRight.leftMargin = this.resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.margin_selector)
}
```